# reference dependent property of object within MATLAB gui code

Tags: matlab, oop, user-interface, properties

I have a LaunchSimulation class that has some dependent properties that need to be calculated whenever the property is referenced. I am trying to access these properties inside a button callback of my GUI file. I create my simulation object inside the openingFcn and am able to reference the regular properties just fine, but when I try and reference any dependent property, it says that the field does not exist.

How can I access the dependent properties? I am not too sure why they do not exist.

Below is my LaunchSimulation class:

```
classdef LaunchSimulation < handle

    %% Constants
    properties (Constant)
        g = 9.81 % m/s^2
    end

    %% Properties
    properties
        launcher
    end

    %% Dependent Properties
    properties (Dependent)

        horizontalRange
        verticalRange
        timeOfFlight

    end

    %% Non-static Methods
    methods

        %% constructor
        function this = LaunchSimulation(launcher)
            this.launcher = launcher;
        end

        %% Launch data computation for user input values
        function computeHorizontalAndVerticalRange(this)


            this.launcher.launchVelocity = input('Enter launcher velocity: ');
            this.launcher.launchAngle = input('Enter launcher angle: ');

            DataDisplayer.displayLauncherSettingsTable(this);
            fprintf('Horizontal Range: %f \n', this.horizontalRange)
            fprintf('Vertical Range: %f \n', this.verticalRange)

        end


        %% Getters and Setters

        % horizontalRange
        function value = get.horizontalRange(this)

            value = ((this.launcher.launchVelocity)^2 * sind(2 * this.launcher.launchAngle)) / LaunchSimulation.g;

        end

        % verticalRange
        function value = get.verticalRange(this)

            value = ((this.launcher.launchVelocity^2) * sind(this.launcher.launchAngle)^2) / (2 * LaunchSimulation.g);

        end

        % timeOfFlight
        function value = get.timeOfFlight(this)

            value = ((2 * this.launcher.launchVelocity) * sind(this.launcher.launchAngle)) / LaunchSimulation.g;

        end

    end
end
```

and here is the relevant code for the GUI file

OpeningFcn:

```
% --- Executes just before RocketLauncherSimulationGUI is made visible.
function RocketLauncherSimulationGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to RocketLauncherSimulationGUI (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for RocketLauncherSimulationGUI
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% Instantiate a launcher object with zeroed property values
launcher = Launcher(0,0,0,0);

% Instantiate a simulation object
simulation = LaunchSimulation(launcher);
```

Here is where I try and reference the dependent properties in the callback:

```
% --- Executes on button press in buttonSimulate.
function buttonSimulate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Set the launcher data
simulation.launcher.springConstant = get(handles.editSpringConstant, 'String');
simulation.launcher.projectileMass = get(handles.editProjectileMass, 'String');
simulation.launcher.launchVelocity = get(handles.editLaunchVelocity, 'String');
simulation.launcher.angle = get(handles.editLaunchAngle, 'String');


% This is the part that does not work. For some reason these fields do not exist
% Construct data matrix for table using simulation object
tableData = {simulation.launcher.springDisplacement ...
           % simulation.horizontalRange              ...
           % simulation.verticalRange                ...
           % simulation.timeOfFlight};

% Set the data of the table
set(handles.tableSimulationData, 'Data', tableData);
```

Comment: Where do you actually define the `springDisplacement` property?

Comment: It's in the launcher class, which isnt show, but its similar to the LaunchSimulation dependent properties. All of them have the same issue of not existing

Comment: Can you include the launcher class? Because the issue could be there since all of your dependent properties of the class you show depend upon it. At least the bare minimum

Comment: I just figured it out. I needed to add my simulation object to the handles structure after I create it. When the openingFcn finishes execution any local variables created inside cease to exist. This information came from http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html